# Proving that a symmetric bilinear form on $L$ is invariant

Tags: lie-algebras, bilinear-form, hopf-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $\rho: L \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ a finite-dimensional representation of L. Define a symmetric bilinear form on $L$ by $$\langle x, y \rangle_{\rho} = tr (\rho(x) \rho(y))$$

Where $\text{ tr }$ denotes the trace of endomorphisms.

$(a)$ Prove that this form is invariant, i.e., we have $$\langle [x,y], z \rangle_{\rho} = \langle x,[y,z] \rangle_{\rho}$$

for all $x,y,z \in L.$

**My thoughts:**

I do not know how exactly to do this, specifically how to expand the trace. I know that the Lie bracket of a Lie Algebra satisfies antisymmetry and Jacobi identity but still how to use this to prove the required. Could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: Are you familiar with the identity $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ that holds for all square matrices $A,B$ of the same size?

Comment: Yes I am @JyrkiLahtonen but how this will help me here?

Comment: Good! In a representation the Lie bracket becomes a commutator. Therefore both sides of the identity you want to prove involve two terms, each a product of three matrices. One term is actually the same on both sides. The other...

Comment: $tr(ABC)=tr(A(BC))=tr((BC)A)=tr(BCA)$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how do you know that in a representation the Lie Bracket becomes a commutator?

Comment: Brain, note that $\rho$ maps to $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$, whose Lie bracket is given by $[A,B]=AB-BA$, as you know. Thus we have $\rho([x,y])=[\rho(x),\rho(y)]=\rho(x)\rho(y)-\rho(y)\rho(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any trace form is invariant because of ${\rm tr}([A,B]C)={\rm tr}(A[B,C])$ for $A,B,C \in {\rm End}(V)$.

Indeed, using Jyrki's comment with ${\rm tr}(BAC)={\rm tr}(ACB) $ we have
$$
{\rm tr}([A,B]C)={\rm tr}((AB-BA)C)={\rm tr}(ABC-BAC)={\rm tr}(ABC-ACB)={\rm tr}(A[B,C]).
$$

Comment: but where is the  action of the $\rho$?

Comment: I believe we have an angle brackets and not just parentheses .... does not the angle brackets means inner product?

Comment: You have defined your "angle brackets" yourself by $\langle x,y\rangle={\rm tr}\rho(x)\rho(y)={\rm tr}(AB)$. So it is a trace form, hence invariant. We have written $A=\rho(x)$ and $B=\rho(y)$ as matrices.